# How to debug an c program with args in vscode?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I use the following command to debug when using gdb `gdb --args ./mdriver  -t ../traces/  -v`. Is any tutorial that how i should configure the `launch.json` in vscode to achieve the same purpose? I followed the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9gnSGKYIg4) provided by vscode. But when i want to add `miDebuggerArgs`, it is not available with the warning `Property miDebuggerArgs is not allowed.`
[The whole project is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoSJN.png)